# Is there a way to determine the shape and scale parameters of weibull distribution whith only a value available for time between failures?

Tags: r, weibull

I'm trying to define shape and scale parameters for the weibull distribution based on a dataset. I'm using the "eweibull" function of the EnvStats package. However, when I have only one value for the time between failures, I get the following error:

```
Error in eweibull(x) :
  'x' must contain at least 2 non-missing distinct values, and all non-missing values of 'x' must be non-negative.  This is not true for 'x' = x
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So you only have a single observation?

Comment: That's right! Only a single observation..

Comment: Unless you go Bayesian then no. You can't fit two parameters with a single observation.